# Convert datetime to ddmmyyyy in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to convert datetime to ddmmyyyy as string/varchar in sql server. Let me repeat, not dd/mm/yyyy. I have searched and found only related to dd/mm/yyyy

```
Datetime           VARCHAR
'02-07-2014'       '02072014'
```

Comment: Is this a question or a dare?

Comment: Lolz no, i need it urgently. Please try to help if you can. :)

Comment: just replace "-"to "" blank .
select replace (convert( date,getdate(),101),'-','')

Comment: more precise close to this question
select replace ( convert( varchar,getdate(),105) ,'-','')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select Replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 103),'/','')`

OR

`select substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103),1,2) + substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103),4,2) +
substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103),7,4)`

will does the same

Input: `02-07-2014`

This will give output:

`02072014`

Answer (score 2):

**SQL Code:**

```
Replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 103),'/','')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your date in 103 format (dd/mm/yyyy) and then remove / using replace:

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), <INSERT DATE>, 103), '/', '')
```